# How to use single instance of Selenium WebDriver in multiple java classes including hooks?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, hook, picocontainer

I want to use single instance of WebDriver across multiple classes.

I have `pageObject.java` class that contains web elements and actions ex: click links, send value, etc.

```
public class pageObject {

    private WebDriver driver;

    private BaseTest baseTest;

public pageObject(BaseTest baseTest) {
        this.driver = baseTest.driver;
    }
```

I have another class `stepDefinitionTest.java` that contains BDD glue code.

```
public class stepDefinitionTest {

    pageObject homepage;

    private BaseTest baseTest;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public stepDefinitionTest(BaseTest baseTest) {
        this.baseTest = baseTest;
        driver = baseTest.driver;
    }
```

I have third class `BaseStep.java` that contain @Before and @After method for setup and close browser.

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;

public class BaseTest {

    public WebDriver driver;
@Before
    public void before(){
code
}
@After
    public void after(){
code
}
```

This isn't working and I'm failing to understand the root cause.

error message

```
Step failed
org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$UnsatisfiableDependenciesException: StepDefinitions.stepDefinition has unsatisfied dependency 'interface org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver' for constructor 'public StepDefinitions.stepDefinition(org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver)' from org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer@2fb0623e:2<|
```